# Building android kernel from source gives me error! (Lenovo TAB 2 A8-50F)

Tags: android, build, compilation, kernel

I've successfully flashed a wrong boot.img onto my tablet, and i cannot turn it on now. (yeah, i've got a bootloop)
I've already downloaded the SP flash tool and the original source code but somehow i cannot compile the kernel from it...i guess, something is missing.
Here is what i did so far:

```
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9
cd android
tar xvf lenovo_tab_2_a8-50_osc_201505.tar.gz 
export ARCH=arm64
export CROSS_COMPILE=~/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/bin/aarch64-linux-android-
make lcsh8735_6tb_a8_l_defconfig
make -j2
```

And I've got this output:

```
drivers/misc/mediatek/gpio/mt6735/mt_gpio_debug.c:21:23: fatal error: gpio_init.h: No such file or directory
 #include <gpio_init.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[5]: *** [drivers/misc/mediatek/gpio/mt6735/mt_gpio_debug.o] Error 1
make[4]: *** [drivers/misc/mediatek/gpio/mt6735] Error 2
make[3]: *** [drivers/misc/mediatek/gpio] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/misc/mediatek] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers/misc] Error 2
make: *** [drivers] Error 2
make: Leaving directory `/home/hunwalk/android/Lenovo_A8/alps/kernel-3.10'
hunwalk@hunwalk-K73SV:~/android/Lenovo_A8/alps/kernel-3.10$
```

Could somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

Error

```
fatal error: linux/netfilter/xt_mark.h: No such file or directory
```

normally arises when you build kernel on *shared folders* or other filesystem which doesn't support links.

Build kernel on local Linux filesystem (ext4, xfs, etc.).

Comment: Well...i have Ubuntu 14.04 installed directly on my hard disk...with ext4 fs

Comment: If directory `/home/hunwalk/android/alps/kernel-3.10` is on your local filesystem, then, probably, sources can come from other filesystems.

Comment: I restarted my computer and it worked...maybe there was something wrong with the $PATH variable? :P But now i have a different kind of error :/

Comment: Check with `git status` that there is no file missed in you build directory. Depending from rebooting PC looks weird.

Answer (score 0):

Edit the ***mt_gpio_debug.c*** file and replace this line `#include <gpio_init.h>` with ' **`#include "gpio_init.h"`** '
It's seems like a typo in most mt6735/mt6753 kernel source codes.

Source: [Github](https://github.com/visi0nary/android_kernel_elephone_p8000/commit/1f591b6b311f07fcf7ec9f6c2cc78b889c29bfaf)